# GhostScript.Net not working Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, ghostscript.net

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I am using GhostScript.Net to convert Pdf files to Png images.  This has worked perfectly fine using Visual Studio 2019.  However, when I moved to VS 2022, Here is my code:

```
                using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer()) //create an instance for GhostscriptRasterizer
            {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile);

                rasterizer.Open(inputFile); //opens the PDF file for rasterizing
                SendEmail sendEmail9 = new SendEmail("Page Count", rasterizer.PageCount.ToString(), "");

                //set the output image(png's) complete path
                var outputPNGPath = @"E:\out.png";

                //converts the PDF pages to png's 
                var pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(100, 1);

                //save the png's

                pdf2PNG.Save(outputPNGPath, ImageFormat.Png);

            }
```

When attempting to save, I receive an error message "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I have also tried the GhostScript.Net Fork without success.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same issue. Seems like the rasterizer.GetPage(100,1) returns null. Weird thing is if you do execute it again you will have a result (for me however its just a blank white page)

EDIT: Found the solution!
There seems to be an updated Interpreter with latest Ghostscript versions.
Add

```
rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dNEWPDF=false");
```

right below your using. This uses the old interpreter.

Kudos to this guy: [cannot convert pdf page to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72392622/cannot-convert-pdf-page-to-image)